# Data structure for fast searching words consisting of given letters

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, rust

Given a random string, I want to find every word in a dictionary that consists of only those letters. Input characters can be ignored, so for the string "ccta" we could find "act" or "cat".

How should I implement a data structure to accomplish this goal?

It could be just a plain text file, but that would be slow and not interesting. My thoughts are to first build a frequency map for the given string:

```
pub trait FreqMap {
    type Content;
    type Count;

    fn frequency_map(&self) -> BTreeMap<Self::Content, Self::Count>;
}

impl FreqMap for str {
    type Content = char;
    type Count = usize;

    fn frequency_map(&self) -> BTreeMap<char, usize> {
        let mut freqmap = BTreeMap::new();
        for c in self.chars() {
            *freqmap.entry(c).or_insert(0) += 1;
        }
        freqmap
    }
}
```

Then I would build some data structure which could be "indexed" by such frequency maps. I could convert a dictionary into such structure and searching will be very fast.

What is the best way for indexing a dictionary by such a frequency map?

Comment: So basically you want something that can pay Scrabble? :)

Comment: @biziclop not exactly, but something that can play scrabble i thik can do what I want.

Comment: @coredump: Oh! So you want a full on scrabble solver? You may not be able to build the full-on mapping in memory then...

Comment: How would an input of "ccta" give you "cat" or "act"? Do you propose that duplicated letters be ignored? So that if the user input "ot", you'd get "to", "too", "toot", "tot", and "[otto](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/otto)"?

Comment: Can this be done with transducers? It seems it's pretty similar to the Levenshtein automaton http://blog.burntsushi.net/transducers/

Answer (score 2):

For the dictionary part, I think you may use Trie data structure.
You can know more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) and a good implementation (in C, though) and tutorial [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/).

It is essentially a search tree which can store strings, or rather string prefixes, making it perfect for implementing dictionaries.

You can first build Tries for the words in your dictionary. For instance, one trie for each alphabet so that all the words starting with that letter are stored together.

For the searching part, a solution (somewhat inefficient, though) might be to generate all the permutations of your given string, and search them in the created tries. If a match is found for any prefix of the permuted string, it can also be returned.

Answer (score 0):

1) Sort the unique letters in each word.  Then make a dictionary that maps each sorted-letter-string to the list of words contain exactly the same letters.

2) Make a Patricia trie (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) containing all the sorted-letter-strings.

To do a search, first make a set of the valid letters.  Then you can do a depth-first search on the Patricia trie to find all the entries containing only those letters, and expand the associated lists of words.  This is a normal depth-first search, except you stop following a path when it contains a letter that's not in the valid set.

When you sort the word strings, use an ordering that puts the least-common letters first.  That way the trie will be shallower and your DFS will have to search fewer branches on average.

Comment: Could you expand on your answer to show how you'd go from an input of **ccta** and arrive at **cat**?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of algorithms, having a way to reduce each word into a key which:

- equals the key of another word with the same letters (shuffled)
- differs from the key of another word with at least one different letter

and then using a dictionary `key -> [word]` seems like a reasonable choice.

For the key I would propose using a sorted `Vec<char>`as it is likely more efficient than a `BTreeMap`. Most notably, the vector only has a single memory allocation and its comparison is a straightforward `memcmp`.

For the dictionary, I would propose using a `HashMap`: `HashMap<FreqMap, Vec<String>>`.

---

How to go from **actt** to **act** and **cat**?

- Search for **actt**, find **tact** (and maybe others).
- Search for **act**, **att** and **ctt** (removing one letter each time) and find **act**, **cat** and **tat**.
- ...

Not the most efficient, but you don't have any way to store every possible input in memory.

---

*Remark: `char` are unicode code points, but not graphemes. Depending on the languages/strings you process this may matter; for example if the letters `á` `é` are encoded as `a` + `´` and `e` + `´` respectively, then `aé` and `áe` would both yield the same key (`a`: 1, `e`: 1, `´`: 1) even though they differ.*

Comment: Any reason for a `HashMap` vs `BTreeMap`?

Comment: @Shepmaster: more compact representation, less pointer indirection, in short more CPU-cache-friendly which should help given how many words there are in a dictionary.

Comment: Could you expand on your answer to show how you'd go from an input of **ccta** and arrive at **cat**?

Comment: @Shepmaster: That wasn't a requirement when I answered :/ I fear that it's much more complicated. There are 26 combinations of **act** + any letter that leads to **cat**, 26 * 26 combinations of **act** + 2 any letters that lead to **cat**, ... I am afraid there's not enough memory on the computer for every single input (unless you really limit the upper size), so you have to go the other way around. I would expect to start from the input, build the key, search for it, then iterate over any combination of input - 1 letter, build the key, search for it, ...